# How to use multiple functions in single html dom event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to html dom that's why i don't know too much about it. I want to execute two functions in single html dom event. Here is the code.

```
<a id="link1" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('link1').style.background-color='red'; 
setTimeout(function () {window.location.assign='http://www.google.com'}, 5000);"> Read it</a>
```

Here i want to execute two functions. One is background color and second is opening google after 5 seconds, How can i get it in html dom. Please help me thanks.

Comment: why you don't use onclick="fnName()"?

Comment: when i use fnName() its get executed in multiple pages. I want to execute it on only 3  pages.

Comment: You should really not be hardcoding Javascript into `onclick` attributes, you should be writing pure Javascript in a .js file, attaching *event handlers* programmatically. Then the answer would be more obvious too.

Comment: assign loads a new page in same window Thanks

Comment: `window.location.assign` is a *function*.  You need to call it.  `window.location.assign('http://www.google.com');`.  If you want to use `=`, you just do `window.location='http://www.google.com';`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code:

```
<a id="link1" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('link1').style['background-color']='red'; 
setTimeout(function () {window.location.assign('http://www.google.com'), 5000);"> Read it</a>
```

1. `background-color` has a dash and it is not a valid identifier so you need to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation).
2. `window.location.assign` is a [function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp).